# For two dimentional array ERROR=Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Cannot use string offset as an array” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058635/cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-error)

```
    <?php

        $marks  = 0;
        $total  = $_POST["lines"];
        $quesA  = $_POST["ques"];
        $quesNo = 1;
        $opt    = array("","A","B","C","D");

        for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
        {
            $q = $quesA[$i][0]; // here error

    ...
```

Here I assign `$quesA = $_POST["ques"];` now it take a variable `$q = $quesA[$i][0];` then print in line

```
echo "<div><b style='color:red;'>Q" . $quesNo . " : </b>"
     . "<span style='color:blue;'>" . $q ."</span></div>"
;
```

here is my code: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24972447/onlineQuiz.7z

Comment: Stop using a string variable as an array. Your error will go away then. Also please search on the site before posting a question.

Comment: I search about 3 hours, then I post. No where I didn't get accrued answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$quesA[$i]` is not a valid array and you are trying to use it like an array.

Am not sure how you are getting `$_POST["ques"]` but you need to make sure its an array before you can access it.

Post what you are expecting from `$_POST["lines"]` & `$_POST["ques"];` i may be able to help further

Comment: if u put 0 on $i in $quesA[$i] then same error.
$_POST["lines"] means $ques[][] array length and $_POST["ques"]; means $ques[][] array in previous from. I can use print_r($quesA); then it works.

Comment: You can never get array lengths that way .... you can only use PHP `count`

Comment: yes only in php. length is not my concern. I want to assign a new array for replacing previous from array.

Comment: here is my code:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24972447/onlineQuiz.7z

Comment: Let me check it out .. hold on

Comment: You are sending `$ques` as `<input type='hidden' name='ques' value='<?php print_r($ques); ?>' />` that is not a way to send information as array via POST

Comment: then how can I do it right way. help me. I'm bored.

Comment: remove `<input type='hidden' name='ques' value='<?php print_r($ques); ?>' />` then let your input be like this `<input type='radio' name='".$quesNo."' id='".$opt[$j]."' value='".$ques['ques'][$i][$j]."' />`

Comment: $ques['ques'][$i][$j] is it will be $ques['ques'[$i][$j]]
still error!!

Comment: This are basic rules please try this example to see a prof of concept http://codepad.org/CzA5jViA

Answer (score 0):

After

```
$quesA=$_POST["ques"];
```

$quesA is a string, not a multidimensional array, so $quesA[$i] gives you the (i+1)th character of the string (the "string offset" of the error message).

You cannot use the index operator on that.

Comment: I need how to print previous from array in current from by assigning a new array. but I took in a string. so now how I can do it.