# Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, offset

> Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\categories\categories.php on line 12

```
$categories[$parent][] = $row;
```

**categories.php**

```
    <?php

$sql = "SELECT catid, catname, parentid FROM categories";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $parent = intval($row['parentid']);
    if (!isset($categories[$parent])) {
        $categories[$parent] = array();
    }
    $categories[$parent][] = $row;
}
    ?>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
    <?php
    $category_string = "";
    function build_categories_options($parent, $categories, $level) {
        global $category_string;
        if (isset($categories[$parent]) && count($categories[$parent])) {
            $level .= " - ";
            foreach ($categories[$parent] as $category) {
                $opt_value = substr($level.$category['catname'],3);
                $category_string .= '<option value=""></option><option value="'.$category['catid'].'">'.$opt_value.'</option>';
                build_categories_options($category['catid'], $categories, $level);
            }
            $level = substr($level, -3);
        }
        return $category_string;
    }
    $category_options = build_categories_options(0, $categories, '');
    $category_options = '<select class="chosen" name="categories" id="categories">'.$category_options.'</select>';
    echo $category_options; 
    ?>
</td>
```

**After I insert post With category This Error Will Show ??**

Comment: can you point out line 12 please

Comment: What is `$categories`? I bet it's a string...or `$categories[$parent]` is a string.

Comment: im thinking the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058635/cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-error

Comment: @Flosculus Thanks Man My Problem Is Fixed

Comment: @Travesty3 I need Your Help !! Please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650424/how-can-i-use-get-with-build-categories-options-function#comment17064106_12650424
my code working done but i need to use in this line  $category_string .= '<option value=""></option><option value="'.$category['catid'].'">'.$opt_value.'</option>'; in this Option <option something like  that value="$_get['catid']">$_get['catname']</option> like this to display catname from table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see where `$categories` is initialized, but I'm betting that it's not an array when you enter your `while` loop, and that's why you're getting an error. Try doing this for your `while` loop:

```
// initialize $categories to make sure it is an array
$categories = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $parent = intval($row['parentid']);
    $categories[$parent][] = $row;
}
```

You don't need to explicitly initialize `$categories[$parent]`...this will be done automatically when you call `$categories[$parent][] = $row;`. We know that it will start out blank because we started with an empty array before the loop.