# How Can i use $_get with build_categories_options function

Tags: php, mysql, function, get, categories

Now I have create categories and create post is successful but when I edit my post I have problem if edit my post I will lose my category .. I need to get my category in table and I can change it

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT catid, catname, parentid FROM categories";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

// initialize $categories to make sure it is an array
$categories = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
$parent = intval($row['parentid']);
$categories[$parent][] = $row;
    }
    ?>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">

    <?php
    $category_string = "";
    function build_categories_options($parent, $categories, $level) {
        global $category_string;
        if (isset($categories[$parent]) && count($categories[$parent])) {
            $level .= " - ";
            foreach ($categories[$parent] as $category) {
                $opt_value = substr($level.$category['catname'],3);
                $category_string .= '<option value=""></option><option value="'.$category['catid'].'">'.$opt_value.'</option>';
                build_categories_options($category['catid'], $categories, $level);
            }
            $level = substr($level, -3);
        }
        return $category_string;
    }
    $category_options = build_categories_options(0, $categories, '');
    $category_options = '<select class="chosen" name="categories" id="categories">'.$category_options.'</select>';
    echo $category_options; 
    ?>
</td>
```

My problem located in line 25

```
$category_string .= '<option value=""></option><option value="'.$category['catid'].'">'.$opt_value.'</option>';
```

I need to get my category in first  and show the rest of the results.

Comment: mysql_query is going out.. Remember to check Mysqli before you ever plan to upgrade

Comment: Seems like you are only calling the record with catid 0..  Is there value in that entry? What is the output and the expected output?

Comment: @MoeTsao thanks For your feedback ;) but i think you don't understand me my code working done u need to use 
$category_string .= '<option value=""></option><option value="'.$category['catid'].'">'.$opt_value.'</option>';
in this Option <option value="$_get['catid']">$_get['catname']</option> like this to display catname from table ??

Comment: Sorry really having trouble understanding what you are trying to say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each category, you are displaying two options, an empty option and one with the category information:

```
$category_string .= '<option value=""></option><option value="'.$category['catid'].'">'.$opt_value.'</option>';
```

This is inside your loop. So every time your loop iterates, **two** options will be created. A blank one and one with your category. I'm betting you just need **one** blank option at the very beginning of the `<select>`. I think this is what you wanted:

```
// notice we are initializing $category_string with an empty option here
$category_string = '<option value=""></option>';

function build_categories_options($parent, $categories, $level) {
    global $category_string;
    if (isset($categories[$parent]) && count($categories[$parent])) {
        $level .= " - ";
        foreach ($categories[$parent] as $category) {
            $opt_value = substr($level.$category['catname'],3);

            // removed extra empty category and put it in $category_string initialization
            $category_string .= '<option value="'.$category['catid'].'">'.$opt_value.'</option>';
            build_categories_options($category['catid'], $categories, $level);
        }
        $level = substr($level, -3);
    }
    return $category_string;
}
```

Also, as @MoeTsao mentioned in the comments, try to avoid using [`mysql_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) functions, as their use is discouraged by PHP. Instead, use [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

Comment: thank you .. but id do blank to get value = 0 = main category parent id=0 .. now i need something easy i think !! when update my post i need to display category in this post how can i display category and change it if i want ??

Comment: Try something like this: `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $category['catname']; ?>" />`

Comment: i already do it :D <?php
$sql2 = mysql_query("Select categories.catname, categories.catid, categories.parentid, users.name from categories, users where catid='$categories' limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows2 = mysql_num_rows($sql2);
if($num_rows2 >= 1)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{
extract($row);
?>
<h2><?php echo $row['catname']?></h2>
<?php 
}}
?>  </div>

<div class="field fullwidth">
<?php include_once( 'includes/categories/editcatwithparent.php' ); ?>
</div>

Comment: when i do this echo $category['catname']; input didn't show with function !! .. when click edit post show to me catname,parent id is null :S i need to show cat name with function and function allowing me to change if i want

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding you. It sounds like what you want to do is fetch the data from the database, populate the values in a `<form>`, and update the values when the form is submitted. Is that right? If so, don't use `<h2>` elements. Use `<input>` elements, set their `type` attribute to "text", and set their `value` attribute to the category name, like this: `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row["catname"]; ?>" />`. If I'm misunderstanding, give [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wT) a shot.

Comment: :D Thanks For You problem solved ;) im do it like  $category_string = '<option value="'.$_GET['catid'].'">'.$_GET['catname'].'</option>';