# How to fix error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: php

I'm working on some old PHP website and cannot figure out how to fix this kind of error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array

This is the part where the error is being thrown

```
$ret["content"]["news"] = array();
$start = ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows;
$stop = ($count > $start + $page_rows) ? $start + $page_rows : $count;

for($i = $start; $i < $stop; $i++)
{
    $cnt = sizeof($ret["content"]["news"]);
    print_r($ret);
    $ret["content"]["news"][$cnt] = $this->getPost($all[$i]);           
}
```

`print_r` returns

> Array ( [content] => A [template] => intro )

Error is being thrown at this line

```
$ret["content"]["news"][$cnt] = $this->getPost($all[$i]);
```

Full code source: https://pastebin.com/aPC2suL5

Comment: EXACTLY where is it being thrown?

Comment: here ```$ret["content"]["news"][$cnt] = $this->getPost($all[$i]);```

Comment: what is the type of $ret["content"]["news"]? If not array it will throw error

Comment: var_dump($ret["content"]["news"]);

Comment: it returned string(1) "A"

Comment: content news is not an array, so you cant access content news $cnt

Comment: You're not showing us all of your code in the script?

Comment: `$ret["content"]` is a __string__. What do you expect by adding `[news]`?

Comment: Something you're saying is not correct.  You can't have `print_r($ret);` output `Array ( [content] => A [template] => intro )` _and_ have `var_dump($ret["content"]["news"]);` "returned string(1) 'A' "

Comment: https://pastebin.com/aPC2suL5 This full code, at the beginning $ret is being initialized as an array

Comment: you seem to have a strange obsession with `md5` as well

Comment: As has been mentioned, your code is setting `$ret["content"]` to various string values. `$ret = array("content" => "", "template" => "intro");` and `$ret["content"] = $this->getPost($_GET["id"]);` and `$ret["content"] = "Nothing here";` all do this. If you later want to make `$ret["content"]`, then you probably need to initialize it as such first by doing `$ret["content"] = array();`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cannot use string offset as an array" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058635/cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-error)

Comment: @Martin Thank you, you helped me figure out the problem, now this working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many parts of your code are type-swapping your variables; mixing `arrays` and `strings`. Try the below:

```
for($i = $start; $i < $stop; $i++)
{
   // Debug only. Remove once bugs are squashed. 
   if(!is_array($ret["content"])){
      error_log("You've set ret['content'] as a non-array; probably a string!");
    }  
    if(!is_array($ret["content"]["news"])){
        error_log("You've set ret['content']['news'] as a non-array too!");
    }
    //end debug block
    /***  
     * You do not need to count the array values each time, simply append with []
     ***/
    $ret["content"]["news"][] = $this->getPost($all[$i]);           
}
```