# PHP File Upload does not work

Tags: php, file-upload

I am having trouble removing spaces from a file name in php. The file does not upload to the server once the file is submitted. Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('djmann1013');

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['auth'])){
    header('Location: /');
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo $username;

$dirs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `usr_name` = '" . $username . "'") or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($dirs);
$dir = $r['usr_directory'];

if(isset($_FILES['upload'])){
    $file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $_FILES['upload']['name']);
    $current_time = date('n/j/Y ');

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `uploaded_files` (`username`,`file_name`,`time_updated`) VALUES('" . $username . "','" . $file . "','" .  $current_time . "')") or die(mysql_error());
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "usr_files/$dir/$file");
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home - LAN File Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Upload a file</h1>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="upload" id="file"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<b>Note: the larger the file, the longer it takes to upload.</b>
<h1>Account Settings</h1>
<b><a href="/file_browser.php">Your Files</a></b>
<b><a href="settings.php">Account Settings</a></b>
<b><a href="/?action=logout">Logout</a></b>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You need to move the file out of temp 1st: http://us2.php.net/move_uploaded_file

Comment: @user574632 OP is calling `move_uploaded_file`.

Comment: do you have any errors, warnings, notices? Is code inside if(isset($_FILES['upload'])) run?

Comment: @robson I have no errors, but the form disappears after submitting the form and the file does not appear on the server.

Comment: Is `usr_files/$dir` writeable and where you expect it to be? Try some debugging like `if (!move_uploaded_file(...)) { throw new Exception('Error moving file to ' . realpath("usr_files/$dir/$file")); }`

Comment: Also, **always** use `exit` immediately after issuing a *Location* header. See http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction.aspx

Comment: I was able to upload to the folder before. I don't know why the folder would randomly be locked.

Comment: If you are getting nothing, that usually means you have an error somewhere but `display_errors` is set to off in your php.ini or error_reporting is off. Check your error log to see what problems you are having. Errors will still be written to the log even when not displayed to screen.

Comment: Where is the log file located?

Comment: @Fred the usr_directory isn't undefined when I execute it. It gets the data from the DB.

Comment: Log file would be log of your http server probably e.g. apache if you use it

Comment: You could add also at the begin of your php file: error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_WARNING);

Comment: Are you sure that `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])` returns false?

Comment: @robson I see a file does not exist error in usr_files/username/file_name

file_name is the name of the file
username is the user's folder name

Something is wrong with the upload I think. I don't know what is causing the error because it has no output of the php error.

Comment: Also, error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_WARNING); does not output any errors

Comment: But the file will be in location you mentioned after executing `move_uploaded_file` command. Before that it is uploaded to temp directory. You can check that by `is_uploaded_file` function. Did you try with `error_reporting` function I have written above? Did you check if the file is uploaded to tmp directory at first?

Comment: I got errors: http://pastebin.com/Gue5ZXs8 I don't know if it is the problem though.

Comment: If this is home.php file - there is something wrong with string variables in line 27. Which one is it?

Comment: Line 27 is a `}` in my updated code. You can find the updated code here: http://pastebin.com/Nzf6S0yv

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because of an error in one of the following fields: the SQL query, not valid path used for storing the file or incorrect directory permissions where you want to store that file to.

For either of these errors you need to do a little bit debugging. First you need to enable error reporting in PHP, because it seems to be disabled in your case. Take a look at this question on how to enable it:
[How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Basically you can try inserting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);<br>
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the beginning of your PHP code, right after the opening <?php tag but it might not work for some situations so you better enable it in the php.ini file and then restart the web server.

Your php.ini should have

```
display_errors = on
```

Then after you see what the real error is you'll be able to solve it really quickly.

Comment: The display_erros is on in the php.ini.

Comment: You can ignore the time warning but as you can see there is a fatal error: **Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\home.php on line 27** so just see that line 27 in the home.php. It seems you have a string which you want to use as an array. For more information check [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873970/cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-in-php) and that's how you are supposed to do your debugging until you get error free code and it works :)

Comment: P.S. to fix the first warning you need to set `date.timezone = "UTC"` in your php.ini to either Coordinated Universal Time(UTC) as I showed or to your real timezone as found here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php

Comment: I am downloading the latest build of PHP 5.5.6. Apparently it is a bug in PHP 5 (which currently I have) and hopefully downloading the latest (5.5.6) will fix it.

Comment: Yes because that's not a bug in PHP but error somewhere in the code. That is why I showed you how to debug it step by step. You just need to clear these errors you got one by one until it finally works.

Comment: I found out the file name changes so the spaces are replaced with underscores, so it must be something with storing the file.