# Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in meta.php on line 43

Tags: php, arrays, string, offset

```
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /home/content/51/6183951/html/triadss/wp-content/themes/smartbox-installable/lib/functions/meta.php on line 43
```

**Kindly solve this issue!!!!**

meta.php on line 43 starts with "**array_push**"

```
function get_des_templates($type)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $q = "SELECT * from ".$wpdb->prefix."options WHERE option_name LIKE 'des_template_[$type]_%'";
    $res = $wpdb->get_results($q, ARRAY_A);
    $output = array();
    foreach($res as $r)
    {
        $options = unserialize(trim($r['option_value']));
        if (is_string($options))
        {
            $options = unserialize($options);
        }
        array_push($output, array("id"=>$options['des_template_tab']['name'], "name"=>$options['des_template_tab']['nicename']));
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot use string offset as an array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873970/cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

second argument to array_push should be single item (string).

Please check [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

Try using array_merge