# PHP Fatal Error Cannot Use String Offset As Array

Tags: php

I keep getting a fatal error when a script is ran on my php server,

This web app was built ten years ago and I am currently clearing errors so we can start updating it. Current version `PHP 5.2.17`

```
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /home/user/public_html/admin/script.php on line 1418
```

This is the line the error is on,

```
      $name = $d["@"]["_Name"];
```

This is the full function,

```
        if (isset($b["_BORROWER"]["EMPLOYER"])) {

            if (!isset($b["_BORROWER"]["EMPLOYER"][0])) {
                $temp = $b["_BORROWER"]["EMPLOYER"];
                unset($b["_BORROWER"]["EMPLOYER"]);
                $b["_BORROWER"]["EMPLOYER"][0] = $temp;
            }

            foreach($b["_BORROWER"]["EMPLOYER"] as $c => $d) {
                $pid = '0';
                // Finish up.
                $item["type"] = "Personal";
                $name = $d["@"]["_Name"];
                //check for files in other bureaus
                $query = doquery("SELECT name,id FROM <<myitems>> WHERE cid='".$client["id"]."' AND type='Personal'");
                $results = dorow($query);
                if($results){
                    if(isset($results['name'])){
                        $temp = $results;
                        unset($results);
                        $results[0] = array($temp);
                    }
                    foreach($results as $c){
                        if(isset($c['name'])){
                            if($address == decrypt_string($c['name'])) {
                                $pid = $c['id'];
                                break;
                            };                                  
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Does anyone understand what is triggering this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Well I'm definitely not doubting that this was made 10 years ago. Can you `var_dump($d);` before that line and show us what pops up?

Comment: Make sure `$d["@"]` is an array.

Comment: I was super expecting to get down voted for this. My major problem here is replicating the problem in a dev environment is very hard casue this app is so extensive and this client had no dev env setup. I am sorting through very old code that is in use. This script runs a 3rd party app that charges the client 50 bucks when it runs so I am very skeptical on how to test this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use string offset as an array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873970/cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check the array value exists or not like,

```
$name = isset($d["@"]["_Name"]) ? $d["@"]["_Name"] : "";
```