# How can I correct a string array error message when it appears suddenly?

Tags: php, arrays, string

When accessing a page, I am now receiving the following error message:

> Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in
>   /home/content/01/5335601/html/wp-content/plugins/popup-by-supsystic/modules/popup/mod.php
>   on line 194

No changes were made to the page or popups. The fatal error just appeared.

Have not tried much since I have no earthly idea about code. I did follow the error message to at least locate line 194.

> Line 194:

```
if(isset($p['params']['main']['hide_for_devices'])
```

Would like suggestions on how to correct this issue, especially those that I can understand enough to get the fatal error message removed and the content showing again.

Comment: Please add all thecode. I think one of your indexes could be not correct, but with just this line I am not sure

Comment: There are 400ish lines... should I paste the entire code?

Comment: Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1873970/5144943)?

Comment: `$p` is a string not an array, find where its defined

Comment: Nope post the block where you are working on, if you are in a loop for example, how you set this variable. Have you initialize the $p as an array?

Comment: The error means that either `$p`, `$p['params']` or `$p['params']['main']` is a string rather than an array. If you show the code that fills in `$p` we may be able to figure out which.

Comment: `print_r` or `var_dump` the `$p` to see what you actually have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use string offset as an array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873970/cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-in-php)

Comment: I hope that this will help.... coding is not in my level of knowledge so this is a bit foreign. Also not sure as to how to make the dang lines separate!

Comment: foreach($popups as $i => $p) {
if(isset($p['params']['main']['hide_for_devices']) 
&& !empty($p['params']['main']['hide_for_devices'])
) { // Check if popup need to be hidden for some devices
if(!$mobileDetect) {
importClassPps('Mobile_Detect', PPS_HELPERS_DIR. 'mobileDetect.php');
$mobileDetect = new Mobile_Detect();
$isTablet = $mobileDetect->isTablet();
$isMobile = !$isTablet && $mobileDetect->isMobile();
$isDesktop = !$isMobile && !$isTablet;
}

Comment: well now we need to see what defines `$popups`

Comment: With 50 or so references to $popups within the code, how can I locate or identify the part of the code that defines $popups?