# Cannot access offset of type string on string, laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel-9, inertiajs

I get this error **"Cannot access offset of type string on string"**, how do I fix this error?

this error occurs in my resource file, this is the code in my resource

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
class InvoiceResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'bank' => $this->payment_type == 'bank_transfer' ? [
                'name' => $this->payment_info['bank']['name'],
                'va_number' => $this->payment_info['bank']['va_number'],
            ] : null,
        ];
        
    }
}
```

the error is in this line

```
'name' => $this->payment_info['bank']['name'],
```

what do you think I should do? please help me fix this error ;((

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558957/php-message-php-fatal-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-access-offset-of-type-s)