# error: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: php

I'm helping a client with getting their website ready for PHP8. After doing the update to the latest Joomla and making sure the template is updated, it runs fine on PHP8. I do however get the following error only on one page. The page where you have to create a new user:

```
Error: Failed opening required 
'/usr/www/users/kznden/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php'): Cannot access offset of type string on string
```

I know this path doesnt exist anymore but how can I get rid of this error and the page working again? I opened the error.php file and believe the error is related to that file. If I'm wrong, please correct me. Specifically the following code:

```
$doc->setTitle($this->error->getCode() . ' - '.$this->title);
require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php');
$header_renderer = new JDocumentRendererHead($doc);
$header_contents = $header_renderer->render(null);
```

Removing

```
require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php');
```

doesn't seem to fix the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED93U.png)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error, does Joomla have any error logs available?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem properly? Which of these lines causes the error?

Comment: This error is not thrown in your provided code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558957/php-message-php-fatal-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-access-offset-of-type-s)

Comment: Not sure of the image link shows. I cant yet add an image. Guess I'm too much of a new user yet. But basically the first piece of code in my post is what opens on the page. If I then edit any of the code it doesn't make a difference. I'm really at a loss. On PHP7.4 it works but as soon as I switch to PHP8 it gives the error.

Comment: And which line causes that error? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: I tried editing the code and also to remove it completely. Makes no difference. I'm not even sure what the exact cause is. It's also just on the create new user page. If a user already have a login then the login page works fine.

Comment: If you remove "the code" and the error still happens, then you did not remove the code that triggers the problem

Comment: Any idea which file it might be that still triggers? I changed the error.php of the template. This was suggested elsewhere