# PHP 7.1: Adding values to multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having a problem with this multidimensional array that I just want to add information to, if there is information available from the SQL array $results. This worked great with PHP < 7.1 but now I can't get it to work at all.

See examples below. #1 works fine but #2 and #3 throws a fatal error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array**

```
1. if ($result['type']>0) { $article['object']['type'] = $result['type']; }
2. if (strlen($result['productName'])>0) { $article['object']['manual']['product'] = $result['productName']; }
3. if (strlen($result['brandName'])>0) { $article['object']['manual']['brand'] = $result['brandName']; }
```

How am I supposed to add these values to the array in PHP 7.1+? I have tried "preparing" $article['object']['manual'] by making it an array, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: @Barmar Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Comment: This will happen if one of `$article`, `$article['object']` or `$article['object']['manual']` already has a value as a string rather than an array. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873970/cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-in-php

Comment: I've read that question prior to posting my own and I just can't get it to work, so unfortunately it doesn't help me. This is the first time $article['object'] is used in this function. Why would PHP think it's a string?

Comment: Is `$article` included or required from another script?

Comment: I tried this after iniitializing `$article` to an empty array, and also without initializing it at all, and got no error. I'm using PHP 7.3.

Comment: You say "I have tried "preparing" `$article['object']['manual']` by making it an array". Did you try "preparing" `$article['object']`?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, it worked when I initialized $article itself. I'm pretty sure I tried that before but perhaps not -- anyway, thanks a lot for helping me out. It works now!

Comment: That's weird. Maybe it's a bug they fixed between 7.1 and 7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user Barmar pointed out in the comments, `$article` needs to be initialized as an array for this to work. As soon as I had set `$article = array();` it started to work.